# What does "this" alone refer to in my function?

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, this, keyword

Just trying to wrap my head around exactly what "this" alone in the "updateCell" parameter refers to in this code:

```
function initializeGame() {
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener("click", cellClicked))
    restartBtn.addEventListener("click", restartGame);
    statusText.textContent = `${currentPlayer}'s turn`;
    running = true;
}   
function cellClicked(){
    console.log('test');
    const cellIndex = this.getAttribute("cellIndex");
 
    if(options[cellIndex] != "" || !running) {
        return;
    }
    
    updateCell(this, cellIndex);
    checkWinner();
}
function updateCell(cell, index) {
    options[index] = currentPlayer;
    cell.textContent = currentPlayer;
}
```

I know "this" alone can reference a global variable, but there is no global variable called "this" so I'm a little confused on how this works.

Comment: The value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. Since you didn't include code that calls `cellClicked` and your code has more opening braces than closing ones, it is impossible to say.

Comment: gocha I edited it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback that is passed as argument to `cell.addEventListener` will later be called with `this` set to the DOM element on which the event handler is bound. So in your code that will be `cell`.

If you find the use of `this` confusing, you can use the following instead:

The thing is that the callback is called with an event object as argument. If you prefer, you can also use that event object and its [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property to find out which DOM element is concerned:

```
function cellClicked(evt){
    const cell = evt.currentTarget;
    // At this point, `cell===this` is true
    const cellIndex = cell.getAttribute("cellIndex");
 
    if(options[cellIndex] != "" || !running) {
        return;
    }
    
    updateCell(cell, cellIndex);
    checkWinner();
}
```